# Barrio theme not showing user menu drop-down

Tags: bootstrap-theme

I tried to show the multilevel dropdown submenu for the **user account menu** in subtheme using bootstrap_barrio but it is not showing up. however i did the configuration in the block to show multilevel and put the menu links as expanded.

Answer (score 4):

after investing a lot .. i found that barrio theme is only coming with impelemntation for the navigation menu not for the user account menu . 
what i did is i just copy /templates/navigation/menu--main.html.twig and renamed it 
menu--account.html.twig

and it works fine

Comment: This was driving me crazy for a while. Thanks for posting the solution. :)

Comment: Worked great, nice and easy. I used this solution for two menus that I created, like this: menu--main-menu-left.html.twig and menu--main-menu-right.html.twig